# wxBoxSizer не учитывает высоту статического текста

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

При изменении ширины вертикального `wxBoxSizer` он не заставляет текстовую метку обновить свою высоту для того, чтобы отобразить весь текст (с учетом переноса на новую строку).

| Wide window | Shrinked window |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Wide window] | [image: Shrinked window] |

Фактически перенос слов в wxStaticText работает, но высота не вычисляется по тексту и обновлённой ширине (ширина панели изменяется, сайзер обновляет ширину текстовой метки), а остается исходной.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, L"Test Window")
{
    SetPosition(FromDIP(wxDefaultPosition));
    SetClientSize(FromDIP(wxSize(400, 200)));

    const auto panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    const auto text = new wxStaticText(panel, ID_STATIC,
        L"This is the long string to show inconvinient behaviour of the wxWidgets.",
        wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL
    );
    const auto pnl = new wxPanel(panel, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(100, 100));
    pnl->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(100, 255, 100));

    const auto vbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    const auto textItem = vbox->Add(text, 0, wxEXPAND);
    const auto pnlItem = vbox->Add(pnl, 0, wxEXPAND);

    panel->SetSizer(vbox);
    panel->Bind(wxEVT_SIZE, [textItem](wxSizeEvent &evt){
        const auto sz = textItem->GetSize();
        std::wstringstream ss;
        ss << "(" << sz.x << "," << sz.y << ") (" << evt.GetSize().x << "," << evt.GetSize().y << ")";
        wxLogDebug(ss.str().c_str());
        evt.Skip();
    });

    Center();
}
```

Если растягивать текстовую метку по высоте `const auto textItem = vbox->Add(text, 1, wxEXPAND);`, то переносимый на новую строку текст виден, но нижняя панель (зеленая) оказывается прибита к низу окна.

| Wide window | Shrinked window |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Wide window] | [image: Shrinked window] |

Нужно, чтобы между нижней панелью и текстом не было свободного пространства, а текст полностью отображался в окне. Как этого добиться?